# How show barchart's datalabel in center of chart in vertical bar Chart of Apexchart

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, apexcharts

I need show data label in center of chart
change position in plotOptions->dataLabels  , not what I want

actual display
[image]

need display
[image]

````
var options = {
      series: [{
        data: dataChart
      }],
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 1000
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          barHeight: '100%',
          horizontal: false,
          dataLabels: {
            position: 'center',
            orientation: 'vertical',
           
          },
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
}
      xaxis: {
        type : "category" ,
        categories: dataLabel,
          labels: {
          show: false,
        },
      }
        }
      }
    };```
````